# How to properly insert uploaded image with Jodit editor?

Tags: function, file, insert, upload, jodit

I'm currently having an issue trying to insert an image after it has been uploaded. I've followed the documentation on https://xdsoft.net/jodit/, but still having issues.

Here is my config object:

```
{
  readonly: false,
  enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
  uploader: {
    url: this.url_upload,
    data: {
      dir: this.dir
    },
    baseurl: relativePathURL,
    process: (response) => {
      let files = [];
      response.list.map((file) => {
        files.push(file.name);
      });
      return { 
        files,
        path: relativePathURL,
        baseurl: '/content/assets',
        error: (response.success ? 0 : 1),
        msg: response.message
      };
    },
    defaultHandlerSuccess: (response) => {      
      if (response.files && response.files.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.files.length; i++) {
          let full_file_path = response.path + response.files[i];
          this.selection.insertImage(full_file_path);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I understand the return object from `process` is the response passed on to `defaultHandlerSuccess` where the file gets inserted. However, I keep getting this `o is undefined` error every time.

[image]

I'm looking for some insight on how to properly insert the image. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing some further testing to diagnose the problem.

I renamed the original `node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.min.js` to `node_modules/jodit/build/_jodit.min.js`, and `node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.js` to `node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.min.js`, so I can truly understand the issue.

After doing this, the error was in the `insertImage` function, *line 671*,`defaultWidth` was undefined.
https://github.com/xdan/jodit/blob/master/src/modules/Selection.ts#L655

So the change was simply providing the other two parameters when calling the `insertImage` function as so:

`this.selection.insertImage(full_file_path, null, 250);`

In the provided example (https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/tutorial-uploader-settings.html), there is no mention of the parameters being required.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: I was having the same issue with jodit-react, your solution work perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamacaroBarraez glad I was able to help 